# Azure api management access limitations

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I don’t know if this is possible but I suspect it is.

Can I use azure api management to protect an api endpoint? I’ve got a situation where consumer should be forced to register before being allowed to call my api. The api is just to post data into my system.

Can I use api management to do user registration? If so, how does the api know to trust the request? How does the api know who made the request?

What if I wanted the user to only post values relating to what I wanted them to update? And not be able to update other peoples values?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the use cases. Are you using Azure Active Directory to register users? Are you using App Registrations?

What have you tried looking up on the interwebz?

> Can I use azure api management to protect an api endpoint?

[Yes you can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis).

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts) might be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

I’ve got an api that allows third party authorised consumers to update and manage their own products. 

Let’s say they can set a price / quantity. 

I want to restrict them from updating only their own products but I suspect this is more a ‘claims’ based jwt token determination rather than a api management concern. 

Using identity server rather than AAD

Comment: Then you might need a product with a policy defined to handle inbound requests on the API Management. [Check this one out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies)